# Does "factor" mean simply the multiplication (of any functions, numbers etc)

Tags: terminology

I am sorry I am not directed with the education of math.

But granted, let me ask the above question.

In my language (actually Japanese), the words corresponding with the **factor** and **divisor**, **seem to** have come from English. (Not confirmed.)

Now when teaching (potentially for now to me now) them to kids.

I am sorry to say my question is just as it is at the title.

Does **factor** simply mean the multiplication of any functions, or numbers, **whereas**, the **divisor** means literally and **only** "divide" any numbers, etc?

I am afraid I am a little confused about the relationship between these two terms.

Let me kindly take number 24. The number 24 can be expressed by 24=2*2*2*3 if it is expressed by the divisor(s). Now when considering the same 24, when expressed by the factor, 24=4*6 or either 2*12.

Am I correct about understanding the **meaning and the difference of these 2 terms??**

Kindly let me thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for edting (m_m).

Comment: You are welcome. And welcome to the site!

Comment: Why is there a vote to close? I think the question of differentiating between **factors** and **divisors** is good; I know that this is an issue in my class for elementary school teachers, since textbooks vary depending on the context (specifically in questions about factorization within elementary number theory vs. expressions of the form $a \div b$ in which $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: I am sorry for all of you by bomberding many comments, looks like I get lost. Even after celeriko's kind explanation, I still **smell** there might be something more about the word **factor or factoring** as I am saying at comment line of the answerers......................

Answer (score 7):

From your examples, it seems that you generally understand the two terms and their differences/similarities. as @Karl says, they are more or less interchangeable for most audiences. Below I have elaborated a little bit more on the minute distinctions.

Unfortuneately, both of these words have two different meanings each that are subtle, yet distinct.  I fear this is where your confusion might be stemming from

In general terms, a **divisor** is simply a number that divides another number, whether with remainder or without.  In the following two expressions, $7$ would be the **divisor** even though the result is not an integer.

$$\frac{22}{7} \\ 22 \div 7 $$

In addition, since $2 \cdot 3 = 6$, this also means that $2$ and $3$ are both **divisors** of $6$, in that they divide it without remainders, even though there isn't actually division happening, persay.  A synonymous term for this type of **divisor** is a **factor**.

**Factor** can also used in two different ways 1) as a noun (object), which is like the $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ example above, and 2) as a verb (action).  In 2) **factor** means the action of breaking a number/expression into is composite parts, such as taking the polynomial expression $x^2 + 7x + 12$ and writing it as the equivalent $(x+3)(x+4)$ where $(x+3)$ and $(x+4)$ are also **factors** of the original polynomial.

As you can see they are more or less the same however it may be worth it to show your students the difference if there are confusions that are arrising, i hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Kindly let me add 1. I think I understand. If, I am afraid, you have time, I'm glad should you be able to help me regarding what I asked at the comment line. It **might** the **tendency of the exam**, although when students are asked, for example, "Do prime factoring this number etc etc", then the answer is always ( or it seems they should answer as simply as possible. What I mean here is, when prime-facoring, the students need to answer by the set of multiplication of prime numbers powered by "n". If you ask me an example,

Comment: for example, when students are required to do prime factoring to number 288, the answer should be expressed as **284=2(2)*3(2)*23**. ( Kindly be reminded () means a power ). This give me more pain in my head ( please kindly do not take literally though ), and actually more perplexes me. Is there such a rule **in America's examination** too?? ( = as simply as possible ). Thank you for your answer anyway first. --(m_m)

Comment: Please kindly note what I commented is at Karl's answer's comment line. Sorry.

Comment: That is one of the reasons why I asked this question. It seems, **although may be that is the practice of my country's educational system**, when using divisor, the number or polynominal should be expressed **as much simply as possble**. Kindly be noted that is why I asked this question. Anway thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

The terms are interchangeable as I understand. Factors are divisors.
$2\times2\times2\times3$ is a product of prime factors. The $8$ and $3$ are merely factors.

Having said  that in terms of algebraic long division the expression you are dividing by is known as the divisor. In this sense there could possibly be a remainder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, is there any rule in a case of prime factorization the answer should be discribed by 2 numbers? For example, here [link](http://www.mathsisfun.com/prime-factorization.html) it says **Note: 12 = 2 × 2 × 3 can also be written using exponents as 12 = 2(2) × 3** and the answers of typical tests in my country are written always using exponents such as here [link](http://math.005net.com/3/soinsu.php), for example **98=2×7(2)**. ( () is a power ) Thank you for your answer anyway though.

Comment: You mean $2^3\times3$? I think this is still called a prime factor decomposition.

Comment: If you highlight the maths you can see how to type using mathsjax

Comment: Thank you for your having answered to my persisting question. I am bothering you, I know, but, but, but, you see, as is in your case, for example, 2(2)* ×3, is, yes, the **prime factor decomposition**. Now, kindly take a look at here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), it says **In number theory, integer factorization is the decomposition of a composite number into a product of smaller integers. If these integers are further restricted to prime numbers, the process is called prime factorization.**, so since **I think** for example

Comment: when a number is **decompositted**, for example 192 = 8(2)*3, will you stop here? I am sorry I don't know American educational method, but  here, we are teaching that students break 8(2)=2(12). So, is **this** ( = ending into the prime factorization ) only a practice **in my country??**

Comment: I don't understand the American system either but the terminology is universal. You can factorise a number or write it as the product of its prime factors.

Comment: @KentaroTomono Sometimes for emphasis we (Americans) say "factor completely," since in appropriate contexts writing a quantity as any sort of product can be called factoring.  However, "prime factorization" always means a complete factorization into powers of primes.

Comment: Thank you for your answers both of you, Karl and Michael E2. Specifically to me Michael's answer led me to a **compromisation** about this term, perhaps........